# Passing objects to string[] arg of a new application

Tags: c#, serialization, process.start

So I'm working on a project and I'm starting an application from within an application.

```
UnitOfWork.Current = new UnitOfWork(new PollerContext());
UnitOfWork.Current.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    var launcher = new Launcher();
    var arg = launcher.ObjectToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\..\bin\Debug\Emulator.Exe");
}
finally
{
    UnitOfWork.Current.Commit();
    UnitOfWork.Current = null;
    System.Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Now I need to pass two objects to this second app, I tried to serialize them and pass them as `string[]` argument of the second app but they can't be serialized.

The two objects are `castle.windsor` containers if that can help.

Can these be serialized so that this code works, or is there another way to do this?

```
public string[] ObjectToString()
{
    var obj = ReturnObjects();
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, obj[i]);
            serialize[i] = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return serialize;
}

private object[] ReturnObjects() => new object[] { pollerLauncher, backendLauncher };
```

Comment: All the objects have to be serializable in order to be serialized, that's pretty much a given, this includes all the services inside the container as well. Also note that deserialization requires the actuall types serialized to be present in the receiving application as well. Are you sure it wouldn't be a better idea to just set up the containers in the target application as well?

Comment: the target application is an emulator and supposed to be used in more than 1 application.that's why i can't fill the container based on the current application because the next will have a completely different container minus 1 or 2 services. that are used in the emulator

Comment: Is your other app also C#? Then why not transfer data using [NamedPipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Still, the target application will require all the types to be present, it will effectively contain all the classes that the containers would require to function to be defined inside the emulator as well. Are you aware of this? It would still be easier to pass along configuration that would be used to configure the container in the emulator.

Comment: the link might be broken but i'll definitely look into it

Comment: In any case, I seriously doubt a service container can be serialized, serialization is something that should be explicitly built in, and serializing/transporting a container between apps is not so uncommon that I highly doubt any work at all is done for this. Additionally, all the services inside would have to be serializable as well.

Comment: i'll see if i can isolate the service that will be used in the emulator or if there's another way entirely to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to pass objects directly between two .NET applications is by avoiding starting the second application as a separate process. This is as simple as referencing the exe and calling a method.

Of course, this means it doesn't run as a separate process. But that really can't be avoided if you want objects to be shared. The only exception is remoting, which marshalls calls between applications - but even that requires your objects to coöperate by inheriting from `MarshalByRefObject`.

By default, objects don't make much sense serialization-wise. Serialization is really about data, so if your objects are more than just data containers, you're in trouble. Even if the container itself supported serialization, to really make it work, you'd have to also ensure all the possible objects it might instantiate *also* support serialization. There's no way to enforce this by contract. Even if everyone supports serialization, contracts will be violated - a singleton is no longer a singleton, and you have plenty of opportunities for collisions and other errors (e.g. one object might create a unique id, another will reference it, but when they are serialized, the first one will create a new unique id (to actually keep being unique), while the second will keep referencing the old one).

However, most DI containers also support setup by configuration. This configuration is something you can easily pass between applications, and allows the target to reconstruct a similar dependency tree.

It's not clear what you're actually trying to accomplish, so there's little more I can help with. It's very likely that you're solving the XY problem, have the first part finished, so only the impossible bit remains.

Comment: i've isolated 2 services 1 for each container that are used in the second application. Can these 2 be passed on? Serialization is probably not going to work but any other way

Comment: @AxelBouttelgier There's only the two ways - remoting (which marshalls messages between the two applications, which makes them effectively share the same instances) and serialization (which creates "copies" of the objects in question). Using common configuration to rebuild the "real" objects is a serialization variant that works on the configuration itself. How would you imagine something else to work? What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: I have 2 containers, each have a service used for the emulator(second application) and other services used to support whatever the original application does. In order to seperate the emulator and have it work for multiple projects i need to make sure that the emulator can be used for multiple projects. So i need to seperate the emulator code and the service that belongs to the first project. The containers were originally in the second project that's why i'm trying to find a way to inject the container or the 2 services needed

Comment: @AxelBouttelgier So what you really want is to allow the emulator to make calls against some interface that's common to both projects, right? So all you need to pass to the emulator is either the assembly and type to load and instantiate, or information about how to communicate with the remote service, right? Define the public interface of the emulator and of the "hosted" projects, and code against that - this gives you the separation you're looking for. Whether you pick loading the assemblies or using remote proxies depends on what exactly you need, but either isn't too hard to implement.

Comment: Right now i isolated the service that is used in the emulator, The data that is used in this service is also saved in the database. So i only installed the repository to resolve that part in the second project and recreated everything i need. This way i have the separation i need. There's still a few events that aren't running smoothly but i'll even that out with some debugging and changing.  Thanks for taking the time to look into this it certainly helped me

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look at inter-process communication (IPC) protocols, but basically you're going to have to either create a low-level communication protocol yourself (through raw TCP sockets for example), or (I would suggest) leveraging WCF to abstract away those details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Lasse-v-karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) i looked some more into keeping the container in the second project. i isolated only the parts that would be used in multiple projects and installed those to the container. starting other services is kept into the first project.

so now it works and i don't need extra arguments to start the second project.